# Moving a element sequence value to other element sequence

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a certain requirement where, I need to move the sequence element values to another newly created element according to the the number of values in the original sequence.
Please find my Input XML and the Desired Output XML . 
help is highly appreciated

Rule:
Move the value of Addr1 (catalogue/cd11/Location/Addr/Addr1) to 
catalogue/cd11/Location/primary/original/Address1/place. primary/original/Address1/place need to be created.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.altova.com">
    <publisher>
        <Name id="d123">
            <Place>Chicago</Place>
        </Name
        <catalogue id="d1" >
            <cd11 id="d2">
                <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
                <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
                <year>1985</year>
                <Location id="d1234">
                    <Addr id="d234">
                        <Addr1 id="d565">catherine Av</Addr1>
                        <Addr2 id="d566">block a</Addr2>
                        <City id="d567">chicago</City>
                    </Addr>
                    <Addr id="d334">
                        <Addr1 id="d665">Illinois st</Addr1>
                        <Addr2 id="d666">block a</Addr2>
                        <City id="d667">chicago</City>
                    </Addr> 
                </Location>             
            </cd11>
        </catalogue>
        <catalogue id="d3" >
            <cd11 id="d4">
                <title>Jurassic World</title>
                <artist>Chris Pratt</artist>
            </cd11>
        </catalogue>    
    </publisher>
</root>
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.example.com">
    <publisher>
        <Name id="d123">
            <Place>Chicago</Place>
        </Name>
        <catalogue id="d1">
            <cd11 id="d2">
                <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
                <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
                <year>1985</year>
                <Location id="d1234">
                    <Addr id="d234">
                        <Addr1 id="d565">catherine Av</Addr1>
                        <Addr2 id="d566">block a</Addr2>
                        <City id="d567">chicago</City>
                    </Addr>
                    <Addr id="d334">
                        <Addr1 id="d665">Illinois st</Addr1>
                        <Addr2 id="d666">block a</Addr2>
                        <City id="d667">chicago</City>
                    </Addr> 
                    <primary>
                      <original>
                        <test>test value</test>
                      <Address1>
                        <place>catherine Av</place>
                      </Address1>
                      <Address1>                      
                        <place>Illinois st</place>
                     </Address1>
                  </original>
                    </primary>
                </Location>             
            </cd11>
        </catalogue>
        <catalogue id="d3">
            <cd11 id="d4">
                <title>Jurassic World</title>
                <artist>Chris Pratt</artist>
            </cd11>
        </catalogue>    
    </publisher>
</root>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a template for `Location` elements that inserts the new elements and transforms the `Addr1` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.altova.com" xmlns="http://www.altova.com">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalogue/cd11/Location">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <primary>
                        <original>
                            <Address1>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="Addr/Addr1" mode="convert"/>
                            </Address1>
                        </original>
                    </primary>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Addr/Addr1" mode="convert">
        <place>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </place>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Online sample at http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7mv.

According to your comment and edit you do not want to copy the elements, instead you want to transform them to a new namespace, so you need to change all uses of `xsl:copy` of an element to create an element of the same local name but with the new namespace (which will simply work if you have the right `xmlns="http://www.example.com"` in the XSLT and use `xsl:element name="{local-name()}"`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://www.altova.com" xmlns="http://www.example.com">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalogue/cd11/Location">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <primary>
                        <original>
                            <Address1>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="Addr/Addr1" mode="convert"/>
                            </Address1>
                        </original>
                    </primary>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Addr/Addr1" mode="convert">
        <place>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </place>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: this transform working fine. Thanks for the solution, But how can I achieve without <XSL:copy> as it copies the source namespace. in my case, my source and destination XML document type has different name space. how can it be achieved?

Comment: Well in your posted samples I see `<root xmlns="http://www.altova.com">` for the input and `<root xmlns="http://www.altova.com">` for the output. If that is not right then edit your question and show us which output elements belong to which other namespace.

Comment: @ Martin , I have modified my output XML as needed. Thank you !

Comment: Change the `xmlns=` in the stylesheet to use the wanted result namespace, then add a template `match="*` with the body `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}"><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></xsl:element>`

Comment: I tried the same as you mentioned, but it always copy the old namespace to the element in the template match. In turn, when it validates against the target schema, the whole element is getting removed.

Comment: I think my suggestions in the comment are right and needed, but they don't suffice as there are some other changes needed. I have edited the answer with a complete sample, it is online at http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7mv/1 and the result there looks fine.